# ActionBarSherlock + ListView + Details: how to hide a Layout?

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock 4.1 and my goal is to have two fragments in one screen: a ListView and a details fragment. I've extended the FragmentTabsPager sample found on ABS's website with help [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432228/actionbar-tabs-pager-detail-fragments-inside-viewpager-container).

The exception seems to be related to using the ViewPager. If I want to swipe to a screen for which I want to hide a layout, the application crashes. If I use a tab to switch to the same screen, it works.

I use the following layouts:

**portrait_layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**landscape_layout:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/details_container"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

The magic:

```
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            if (tab.getText().equals("Simple")) {
                countingFragment = new FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment();
                detailsFragment = new FragmentStackSupport.DetailsFragment();
                ft.add(R.id.main_container, countingFragment, "frag1");
                ft.add(R.id.details_container, detailsFragment, "frag2");
            } else {
                // if it's not the first tab
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mContext.getSupportActionBar()
                        .getSelectedNavigationIndex());

                if (countingFragment != null) {
                    ft.detach(countingFragment);
                }
                if (detailsFragment != null) {
                    ft.detach(detailsFragment);
                }
                FrameLayout detailsFragmentLayout = (FrameLayout) mContext.findViewById(R.id.details_container);
                detailsFragmentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            }
        } else {
            //Portrait mode is being used
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mContext.getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());             
        }
```

The idea is to have two containers for the landscape layout and attach fragments to both of them, which works great.

Both containers (content and details) use half the screen (their weights are equal). When I exit a screen that uses the Details fragment, I want to make sure the content container uses all the width and I need to hide the details container somehow.

Unfortunately, the above code (detailsFragmentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)) generates an exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:244)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:678)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:306)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any suggestion on hiding a LinearLayout or perhaps other tips for getting where I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to achieve when using a ViewPager, because the screen has been loaded before it's actually displayed. The ViewPager always loads the next X pages by default. Setting the X value to 0 has no effect, as it reverts to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Insert it into an other layout for example a LinearLayout and set it to INVISIBLE :
`ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: Apart from being essentially the same, it doesn't work either: I get the same exception.