# Android View pager & List fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have successfully gotten a 3 tab + pager implemented.

One of these tabs is a List fragment, how would I update the fragment with the onclick method, and still be able to keep the tabs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot replace a fragment defined statically in the layout file. You can only replace fragments that you added dynamically via a FragmentTransaction.[as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907673/android-cant-replace-one-fragment-with-another)

You can only replace a "dynamically added fragment".

```
private void addDynamicFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               // creating instance of the HelloWorldFragment.
        Fragment fg = HelloWorldFragment.newInstance();
        // adding fragment to relative layout by using layout id
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout, fg).commit();
    }
```

So, if you want to add a dynamic fragment, see this example
check this [link](http://notionink.wikidot.com/rajeshbabu)

Comment: I have used code to make the tab bar and then the tab/pager changes the fragment depending on position, one of those fragments has a listview, I want to know how to add another fragment with the onclick methkd

Comment: see above link and above method to change fragment dynamically.

Comment: I have implemented it as you have suggested but it now shows the old fragment underneath the new one, see image: http://www.philnickl.com/wosm/fragment_error.png

Comment: so you need to remove old one.

Comment: how do I reference the old one from inside another actiity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432228/actionbar-tabs-pager-detail-fragments-inside-viewpager-container?rq=1...hello check here.